# Unable to trigger function from context api with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to trigger a function from my CartContext Api upon a click, but it isn't happening. I have checked the method and it works, but when I add the context function it doesn't do anything... see below code:

Context file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const CartContext = React.createContext({
    cart: [],
    setCart: () => {},
});

const CartContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [updateCart, setUdatedCart] = useState();

    const updateCartHandler = () => {
        console.log('click');
    };

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider
            value={{ cart: updateCart, setCart: updateCartHandler }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default CartContextProvider;
```

Component where Im using the context:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import classes from './SingleProduct.css';
import AddToCartBtn from './AddToCartBtn/AddtoCartBtn';
import { CartContext } from '../context/cart-context';

const singleProduct = (props) => {
    const cartContext = useContext(CartContext);

    const addToCart = (id, productName, price, qty) => {
        const productInCart = {
            productId: id,
            productName: productName,
            productPrice: price,
            productQty: qty,
        };
        cartContext.setCart();
    };

    return (
        <article className={classes.SingleProduct}>
            <div className={classes.ProductImgContainer}>
                <img src={props.productImg} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.ProductTitle}>
                <h2>{props.productName}</h2>
            </div>
            <AddToCartBtn
                clicked={() => {
                    addToCart(
                        props.productId,
                        props.productName,
                        props.productPrice,
                        props.productQty
                    );
                }}
            />
        </article>
    );
};

export default singleProduct;
```

I'm just adding a console.log('click') to check if the method triggers at the moment. By the way, when I console.log the context variable it contains the properties and works. Any ideas why this isn't happening

Comment: Where are you using the provider?

Comment: Did you wrap you `App.js` return components with `<CartContext> </CartContext>` ?

Comment: Thank you! yes, I forgot to do that :P, I thought I did it, but nop! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to wrap the component with provider thanks!